# No output from QProcess

Tags: python, windows, qt, pyqt, qprocess

Why does the following print a blank line instead of 'Hello QProcess'?

```
import sys

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

proc = QtCore.QProcess()
proc.start("echo 'Hello QProcess'")
proc.waitForFinished()
result = proc.readAll()
print result
proc.close()
```

I'm on Windows XP, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because there's no program called "echo".

If you wanted to run this through the shell then you should have used "cmd /C echo Hello QProcess".

Your program also has no error checking.  If you'd checked for errors properly the mistake would have been easier to spot.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide system environment to your proc.

```
proc.setEnvironment(QProcess::systemEnvironment());
```

echo is exceptional command in Windows that does not have executable.